# Problems reading CSV column w/fractional seconds in POSIX format

Tags: r, csv, time

I am reading a CSV file with two columns specifying a date w/time (fractional seconds). The format is like this: 2015-07-13 09:05:52.761, which is originally a factor.
I tried reading the column in using POSIXlt and several variations of this:

```
time_d$time_started_visit <- as.POSIXlt(time_d$time_started_visit, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:M%:%OS")
```

All this did was convert the values of the column to NA. I would really like to convert this so I can get the difference in time between the two columns, any suggestions?

Comment: It seems you managed to read the file correctly and you need a way to convert the datetime column to the appropriate format. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am having trouble reading in data in the format such as: 2015-07-13 09:05:52.761 and convert it a format where I can find the difference in time.

Comment: If the column is originally factors, make sure to convert via "as.character" before using the as.POSIX function.

Answer (score 0):

You used `M%` instead of `%M`

```
# If you wish to retain the fractional seconds 
options(digits.secs = 3)
as.POSIXlt(x, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

Answer (score 0):

You had one little error in your code:

Do not use `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:M%:%OS` but:
`format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"`
You changed `%M` and `M%`

The whole code is then:

```
as.POSIXlt(temp$x, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```